# django modelform property hidden field

Tags: django, properties, hidden-field, modelform

I'm manually displaying my formset as a table, with each form being looped over. At the bottom of each form I include the hidden fields like:

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
```

But the problem is that I am also including properties in my form like:

```
class AllocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '15'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AllocationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['total_budgeted'] = self.instance.total_budgeted()
            self.fields['total_budgeted_account_percent'] = self.instance.total_budgeted_account_percent()
            self.fields['actual_spent'] = self.instance.actual_spent()
            self.fields['actual_spent_account_percent'] = self.instance.actual_spent_account_percent()
            self.fields['total_budgeted_category_percent'] = self.instance.total_budgeted_category_percent()
            self.fields['actual_spent_category_percent'] = self.instance.actual_spent_category_percent()

    class Meta:
        model = Allocation
        exclude = {'created', 'modified', 'source_account'}
```

And this works in the sense that I definitely see the properties being called, however they display as nothing so that's another issue.

The problem is when I keep the hidden fields in the template I will get errors such as 'int' object has no attribute 'get_bound_field' and so on depending on the return type of the property/method call.

My question is **first**: is there a check I can do to see if the field is a property in the template and therefore skip over it?
It may have something to do with how I'm using the property since in fact every property is displaying nothing (but I see it callback), so **second** would be about how to display the properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I am in the next step of the problem, but i have success in generating true form fields. In place of:

```
if self.instance:
    self.fields['total_budgeted'] = self.instance.total_budgeted()
```

You can write:

```
if self.instance:
    self.fields['total_budgeted'] = form.CharField(
        initial=self.instance.total_budgeted(),
        widget=HiddenInput()
    )
```

In this code you I instantiate the form Field as CharField, you can use the FormField you want, and I hide it by choosing the Hidden input widget.